# what is the most important in this sentence the present relevance or the fact that this event belongs to the past?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

http://fluencyspace.com/exercises/mixed-past-tenses/

> It is great to tell people that I have seen  (see) the tallest building in the world!

I know the answer is  present prefect but I think the"seeing of the building" now belongs to the past and past simple seems for me better than present perfect that emphasizes the present relevance

Comment: I have already answered this question, basically: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229673/ago-at-present-perfect-simple/229697#229697 Also, it depends on what **you want to say**.

Comment: so both solutions are ok for you so the answer should include both of them

Comment: may be ! at the end of the sentence implyes present perfect in this case

Comment: No, it does not imply present perfect all: It is great to tell people that I saw the tallest building in the world. The action of seeing could be: last week, last year, and guess what? **You don't even have to say that** [last year, yesterday, etc.]  because English speakers **hear** simple past and present prefect differently. They know simple past refers to a thing that is over.

Comment: and for you in this sentence what is the best solution if there is one

Comment: There is no best solution. It depends  on what you want to say. And I said that in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

As the sentence begins "*it's great that...*", whatever follows is the main focus of the sentence.

It doesn't say "it's great that I saw the tallest building in the world!" so the excitement is not around the past event.

It says "it is great to tell people that I have seen the tallest building in the world!" so the speaker is excited that they *now* get to tell people about this event in the past.